# I am not able to use dynamic imports in vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am developing a web page in vuejs and I am using webpack 4 and babel 6 for compiling the assets

When i put something like... `route('home', '/', () => import('../pages/home.vue'))` the compiler says me `Support for the experimental syntax 'dynamicImport' isn't currently enabled` and I cant use that syntax

I need help, thanks

This is my package.json:
https://gist.github.com/sarmanulco/fd2415c2b81db3df457302c61d77f197

Answer (score 1):

To use vue-router with lazy-loading component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'homepage',
      component: () => import('@/pages/Home.vue') //lazy loading
    },
  ]
})
```

Make sure you take a look at [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org)

Comment: I am not able to do that because says me what I have written right back
Route is a function that returns me the object that you have written, I know what is written in the docs

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you said

Comment: Please, look right back at routes.js in the gist: https://gist.github.com/sarmanulco/fd2415c2b81db3df457302c61d77f197, you will better understand

Answer (score 0):

To use the dynamicImport add a **.babelrc** file (where the package.json is located)

Here is the content of the **.babelrc**:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```